# Is there any way to use cout for debugging while running an ncurses program in another window?

Tags: c++, c, macos, unix, ncurses

I'm playing around with a simple ncurses program to move sprites around a screen. Most of the backend logic is in C++. Apparently Xcode won't with ncurses at all, so I need some other way to debug my program. I don't know C or Unix that well - is there any way I could have my program spawn another Terminal window, which would run alongside the window where ncurses is running? I'd like to be able to use cout in that window to monitor the state of my program.

Comment: Not a solution, but a mere suggestion here. You can write to a file in /tmp and tail the file on another window.

Comment: I guess you could write your debugging messages to a file and in another terminal window run "tail -f thatfile" to follow the last line of output as it happens...

Comment: I may try the file suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use gdb and the "attach" command to attach to your running process.

Comment: I only have LLDB and no experience using a debugger from the command line. I figure I'll have to learn eventually...